# How to recover files after getting permanently deleted

Tags: windows, disk, recovery

So recently, all files of a python project which I had been working on for weeks got accidentally deleted, and then I emptied my recycle bin, so it is gone now.I tried to "Restore Previous Versions" of the folder it was in in windows, but it said that there were no previous versions. So I tried using a disk drill to recover those files, but i could not even find them in the list of files that it came up with. So is there a different setting/configuration on disk drive which could be preventing me from recovering those files? Do I need to use another recovery software?Or is it going to be hard/impossible to recover the file? I have been working on this project for a long time, so  any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you do this on VSCode while using GIT.  Recreate the file in the location you deleted it, then right click on the file and select file history.  You should be able to restore most, if not all, of your data.

Just happened to me, figured this might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any shadow copies to restore a previous version from, then speicalized undelete tools are your only hope. However, if the sectors containing the deleted files' contents have been overwritten since deleting them there is a chance all is lost.